# What does number of nodes mean in ns3 vanet simulation

Tags: omnet++, veins, ns2, ns-3

I have to compare omnet++ and ns3 on basis of vehicular network simulations.

I have a question. In the example vanet-routing-compare.cc in ns3. What does the number of node means??
As i'm importing my own created mobility.tcl file which is obviously generated from Sumo. In omnet++/veins, the amount of vehicles injected per simulation time depends on sumo. However, in ns3, i'm doing it offline.

For example: if my mobility.tcl file looks like this....

```
$node_(0) set X_ 1617.74
$node_(0) set Y_ 1819.07
$node_(0) set Z_ 0
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(0) setdest 1617.74 1819.07 0.00"
$ns_ at 1.0 "$node_(0) setdest 1619.85 1817.75 2.49"
$node_(1) set X_ 1814.92
$node_(1) set Y_ 2144.86
$node_(1) set Z_ 0
$ns_ at 1.0 "$node_(1) setdest 1814.92 2144.86 0.00"
$ns_ at 2.0 "$node_(0) setdest 1623.52 1815.41 4.36"
$ns_ at 2.0 "$node_(1) setdest 1813.87 2143.14 2.01"
$node_(2) set X_ 1895.04
$node_(2) set Y_ 1319.59
$node_(2) set Z_ 0
$ns_ at 2.0 "$node_(2) setdest 1895.04 1319.59 0.00"
$ns_ at 3.0 "$node_(0) setdest 1629.32 1811.66 6.90"
$ns_ at 3.0 "$node_(1) setdest 1811.51 2139.26 4.54"
$ns_ at 3.0 "$node_(2) setdest 1895.89 1318.47 1.44"
$node_(3) set X_ 1892.25
$node_(3) set Y_ 2045.03
$node_(3) set Z_ 0
$ns_ at 3.0 "$node_(3) setdest 1892.25 2045.03 0.00"
$ns_ at 4.0 "$node_(0) setdest 1636.98 1806.71 9.12"
$ns_ at 4.0 "$node_(1) setdest 1808.22 2133.87 6.32"
$ns_ at 4.0 "$node_(2) setdest 1898.29 1316.5 3.12"
$ns_ at 4.0 "$node_(3) setdest 1893.54 2047.1 2.44"
$node_(4) set X_ 1572.19
$node_(4) set Y_ 997.05
$node_(4) set Z_ 0
$ns_ at 4.0 "$node_(4) setdest 1572.19 997.05 0.00"
$ns_ at 5.0 "$node_(0) setdest 1646.53 1800.55 11.36"
$ns_ at 5.0 "$node_(1) setdest 1804.62 2127.96 6.93"
$ns_ at 5.0 "$node_(2) setdest 1903.35 1315.4 5.20"
$ns_ at 5.0 "$node_(3) setdest 1895.68 2050.55 4.06"
$ns_ at 5.0 "$node_(4) setdest 1573.3 998.36 1.71"
$node_(5) set X_ 2650.52
$node_(5) set Y_ 1706.44
$node_(5) set Z_ 0
$ns_ at 5.0 "$node_(5) setdest 2650.52 1706.44 0.00"
$ns_ at 6.0 "$node_(0) setdest 1658.22 1793.0 13.91"
$ns_ at 6.0 "$node_(1) setdest 1800.76 2121.63 7.41"
$ns_ at 6.0 "$node_(2) setdest 1908.82 1319.34 6.98"
$ns_ at 6.0 "$node_(3) setdest 1899.01 2055.91 6.31"
$ns_ at 6.0 "$node_(4) setdest 1576.02 1001.6 4.24"
$ns_ at 6.0 "$node_(5) setdest 2649.84 1704.07 2.47"
$node_(6) set X_ 1794.89
$node_(6) set Y_ 1434.15
$node_(6) set Z_ 0
$ns_ at 6.0 "$node_(6) setdest 1794.89 1434.15 0.00"
$ns_ at 7.0 "$node_(0) setdest 1670.58 1785.02 14.72"
$ns_ at 7.0 "$node_(1) setdest 1796.82 2115.66 7.18"
$ns_ at 7.0 "$node_(2) setdest 1909.78 1326.39 7.30"
$ns_ at 7.0 "$node_(3) setdest 1903.13 2062.53 7.80"
$ns_ at 7.0 "$node_(4) setdest 1580.05 1006.39 6.26"
$ns_ at 7.0 "$node_(5) setdest 2648.73 1700.24 3.99"
$ns_ at 7.0 "$node_(6) setdest 1794.52 1431.93 2.25"
$node_(7) set X_ 2183.23
$node_(7) set Y_ 1481.54
$node_(7) set Z_ 0
$ns_ at 7.0 "$node_(7) setdest 2183.23 1481.54 0.00"
$ns_ at 8.0 "$node_(0) setdest 1681.82 1777.16 13.72"
$ns_ at 8.0 "$node_(1) setdest 1791.22 2110.52 7.61"
$ns_ at 8.0 "$node_(2) setdest 1905.57 1330.8 6.38"
$ns_ at 8.0 "$node_(3) setdest 1907.43 2069.46 8.15"
$ns_ at 8.0 "$node_(4) setdest 1584.74 1011.97 7.28"
$ns_ at 8.0 "$node_(5) setdest 2647.05 1694.43 6.04"
$ns_ at 8.0 "$node_(6) setdest 1793.84 1427.88 4.11"
$ns_ at 8.0 "$node_(7) setdest 2183.13 1483.64 2.11"
$node_(8) set X_ 2662.12
$node_(8) set Y_ 1746.51
$node_(8) set Z_ 0
$ns_ at 8.0 "$node_(8) setdest 2662.12 1746.51 0.00"
$ns_ at 9.0 "$node_(0) setdest 1693.08 1768.94 13.94"
$ns_ at 9.0 "$node_(1) setdest 1786.38 2106.09 6.56"
$ns_ at 9.0 "$node_(2) setdest 1897.99 1332.11 7.85"
$ns_ at 9.0 "$node_(3) setdest 1911.67 2076.28 8.04"
$ns_ at 9.0 "$node_(4) setdest 1589.62 1017.77 7.58"
$ns_ at 9.0 "$node_(5) setdest 2645.31 1688.4 6.28"
$ns_ at 9.0 "$node_(6) setdest 1792.72 1421.93 6.06"
$ns_ at 9.0 "$node_(7) setdest 2182.97 1487.17 3.53"
$ns_ at 9.0 "$node_(8) setdest 2661.59 1744.67 1.92"
$node_(9) set X_ 2657.83
$node_(9) set Y_ 1720.15
$node_(9) set Z_ 0
$ns_ at 9.0 "$node_(9) setdest 2657.83 1720.15 0.00"
$ns_ at 10.0 "$node_(0) setdest 1704.92 1760.29 14.67"
$ns_ at 10.0 "$node_(1) setdest 1781.22 2101.36 7.00"
$node_(10) set X_ 2445.07
$node_(10) set Y_ 2038.34
$node_(10) set Z_ 0
$ns_ at 10.0 "$node_(10) setdest 2445.07 2038.34 0.00"
$ns_ at 10.0 "$node_(2) setdest 1893.21 1336.25 6.37"
$ns_ at 10.0 "$node_(3) setdest 1916.25 2083.65 8.67"
$ns_ at 10.0 "$node_(4) setdest 1594.33 1023.36 7.32"
$ns_ at 10.0 "$node_(5) setdest 2643.69 1683.41 5.25"
$ns_ at 10.0 "$node_(6) setdest 1790.6 1413.54 8.65"
$ns_ at 10.0 "$node_(7) setdest 2182.7 1493.0 5.83"
$ns_ at 10.0 "$node_(8) setdest 2660.58 1741.17 3.64"
$ns_ at 10.0 "$node_(9) setdest 2658.31 1721.84 1.75"
```

What would be the impact if i select number of nodes 5 or maybe 9??
and simulation time 10 seconds?

Comment: Your mobility file is for 11 nodes. If fewer nodes, edit the file, or use another file. ....... About time : Please make sure that the time isn't too short. I.e. some communication must take place, and the trace file(s) must be created before the simulation is stopped. ...... ns3-users: https://groups.google.com/g/ns-3-users

Comment: This is just a small section of my file... i have more than 900 vehicles in my file.

Answer (score 0):

From your question: In omnet++/veins, the amount of vehicles injected per simulation time depends on sumo.

Fact: the periodicity of vehicle injection can be customised in route file in case of veins simulation. Check erlangen.rou.xml file in veins project example.